# Pass data from view to controller using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to select a line of references to get the list of athor reference associat , 
this is the code of my view :

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Réf_OE)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GENER_MOTORS)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Réf_OE)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GENER_MOTORS)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Select", new { Réf = item.Réf_OE }) 
</tr>  
}
```

This the code of my select method :

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Select(string Réf)
    {
        if (Réf != null)
        {
            var autres_ref = db.Autre_Références.Where(c => c.Réf_id == Réf).ToList();
            ViewBag.autres_ref = autres_ref;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Référence_Consctructeur");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Référence_Consctructeur");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Référence_Construscteur");
    }
```

and i put the cursor on select it shows :

```
http://localhost:56616/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence_Consctructeur/Select/7700308756
```

I didn't understand why the paramter passed to select is null
please help.

Comment: Because the parameter name is `Réf` and not `id`.

Comment: thank you , i fixed it now , by changing the name of parametre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter name you are passing in your `ActionLink` should match with the parameter name in your action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Select", new { Réf= item.Réf_OE })
```

Or change the parameter name of your action:

```
 public ActionResult Select(string id){...}
```

Comment: And both actions are defined in the same controller? That should fix the binding problem

Comment: thanks for your help it works fine now , :D the problem was because of name of parametre